# Entity Framework - retrieve only specific columns from multiple navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, viewmodel, navigation-properties

I have a Project entity that has navigational properties ProjectNumbers, Addresses, Contacts, and BBLInfos. I'm trying to select only certain fields of each of the navigational properties and store them in a view model.

The view model looks like this:

```
public class PropertyInfoViewModel
{
    public ProjectViewModel Project { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<ProjectNumberViewModel> ProjectNumbers { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<AddressViewModel> Addresses { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<BBLInfoViewModel> BBLInfos { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<ContactsViewModel> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Calling .Include on the Project DbSet doesn't work because it includes related entities in their entirety.

I was able to get this to work by making a query to each related table separately and selecting the entities whose ProjectId matched the project, but that requires 4 separate table queries. Is there a more efficient way to get related entities while only selecting a couple columns from the related entities?

This is what I am currently doing:

```
 PropertyInfoViewModel model = PropertyInfoViewModel.ViewModelSelector().Invoke(
    new Repository<Project>(epicContext).Get(id),
    new Repository<ProjectNumber>(epicContext).Get(projectNumber => projectNumber.ProjectId == id),
    new Repository<Address>(epicContext).Get(address => address.ProjectId == id),
    new Repository<BBLInfo>(epicContext).Get(bblInfo => bblInfo.ProjectId == id),
    new Repository<Contact>(epicContext).Get(contact => contact.ProjectId == id)
```

The ViewModelSelector then selects only the fields needed:

```
public class PropertyInfoViewModel
{
    public static Func<Project, IQueryable<ProjectNumber>, IQueryable<Address>, IQueryable<BBLInfo>, IQueryable<Contact>, PropertyInfoViewModel> ViewModelSelector()
    {
        return (project, projectNumbers, addresses, bblInfos, contacts, projectInfo) =>
            new PropertyInfoViewModel()
            {
                Project = project,
                ProjectNumbers = projectNumbers.Select(ProjectNumberViewModel.ViewModelSelector()).AsQueryable(),
                Addresss = addresses.Select(AddressViewModel.ViewModelSelector()).AsQueryable(),
                BBLInfos = bblInfos.Select(BBLInfoViewModel.ViewModelSelector()).AsQueryable(),
                Contacts = contacts.Select(ContactViewModel.ViewModelSelector()).AsQueryable(),
            };
    }
```

The ViewModelSelector functions are so I only have to write the ".select" portion of linq queries once and then I can reuse them. The inner ViewModelSelector methods select only specific fields like this:

```
public static Func<Address, AddressViewModel> ViewModelSelector()
    {
        return address => new AddressViewModel()
        {
            ProjectId = address.ProjectId,
            AddressId = address.AddressId,
            StreetNumber = address.StreetNumber,
            StreetName = address.StreetName,
            ZipCode = address.ZipCode
        };
    }
```

Thanks!